# WP7 determining which page I navigated from

Tags: silverlight, navigation, windows-phone-7

I have 3 pages. Page 1 is search criteria, page 2 is list, page 3 is details.

If I go to page 2 from page 1 I want to call a web service and load details onto the page.

If I go to page 2 from page 3 (ie using the back button) I don’t want to reload the data as I already have it.

To determine what to do when page 2 is activated I need to know where I came from.

I can't see anything in the navigating event that tells me this.

Any ideas?

Cheers

Steve

Comment: Why not just check whether you already have the data ?

Comment: Ye if(data == null) Load(); that would be best

Comment: I can't check if I have the data as the VM is a singleton, but your suggestion helped me figure out how to do it using a dataloaded flag and by using navigatingcanceleventargs to check if I am moving back to my list page or back away from my list page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a new (& better?) solution, you should consider using the new (at 12/9/2010) [Non-Linear Navigation Service](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/article/nln-serv-wp7).

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this with the API/SDK as is.

You could, however, have the calling page tell page3 what called it.
One example of how to do this would be to include an entry on the query string. i.e.

```
NavigationService.NavigateTo(new Uri("page3.xaml?from=page2", UriKind.Relative));
```

Then, on page3:

```
string sourcePage;

if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("from", out sourcePage))
{
    // test the value of sourcePage and act accordingly
}
```

Comment: this causes a small problem though, your navigation stack will keep growing and growing despite the fact that the user his hitting back

Comment: @viggity No. why do you say that?

Comment: because you're never going "back", you're only going to (what the navigation service considers) a new page.

Comment: @viggity you cliamed the back stack would grow even if you hit "Back". That can never be the case.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can add a new entry to application's resource dictionary and retrieve it on the next page by overriding OnNavigatedTo method. 
To add entry:

```
App.Current.Resources.Add("from",2);
```

To retrieve the entry:

```
if(App.Current.Resources.Contains("from")
{
   lastPage = (int)App.Current.Resources["from"];
}
```

For more information see Chapter 6 of Charles Petzold book available on the following link:
http://www.charlespetzold.com/phone/