# WP7 know when back key is pressed in the "navigated to" page

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7

In Windows Phone 7, is there a way to know if the back is pressed in the page that's navigated to? I know we can intercept in the current page but I need to know in the page I am navigating to. i.e. if there 2 pages say page1 and page2, back button is pressed in page2. I need to know if back button is pressed or not in page1. I need to run some stuff on back button press in page1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is kind of a hack but you can do the following; override `OnBackkeyPress` event on every page. Within the event handler add the following code:

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["isbacknav"] = true;
```

Then, in the `OnNavigatedTo` event handler for every page, check whether the `State` dictionary contains that entry.

```
bool isbacknav = false;
if( PhoneApplicationService.Current.State.ContainsKey( "isbacknav" ) ) {
   isbacknav = (bool)PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["isbacknav"];

   PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["isbacknav"] = false;
   // or
   // PhoneApplicationService.Current.State.Remove( "isbacknav" );
}
```

Answer (score 25):

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    if (e.NavigationMode == System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationMode.Back)
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is actually better than the accepted answer. Was this available in Windows Phone 7.0 or was it introduced in 7.1/Mango?

Comment: Also you might want to put your answer in a code block so it's easier to read. I would but I can't edit it yet.

Comment: This NavigationMode will also be true when NavigationService.GoBack() is called. If you want only the hardware press use the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

On each page you can override the `OnBackKeyPress` event to detect the back key being pressed.

In that second page you could set a global flag or send a message to the first page.
There's no way for a page to know what the last page that was opened/displayed was. You'll have you to this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly I don't think there's a built in way to do this.

When you get told about OnNavigatingFrom then the event args includes NavigationMode - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigatingcanceleventargs.navigationmode(v=vs.95)

However, when you get told about OnNavigatedTo then the event args don't give you that information.

I think the easiest workaround might be to add a handler for `NavigationService.Navigating` in your App class - you can cache the NavigationMode there. However, test this thoroughly as there may be issues about what code gets in what order - plus there may be problems with whether this code is correctly called when the user navigates back to your page from the Phone home page or from another app

There's a good explanation of  `NavigationService.Navigating` in http://wildermuth.com/2010/10/11/Architecting_WP7_-_Part_1_of_10_Navigation_Framework

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. You can see the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072411/wp7-determining-which-page-i-navigated-from)

I didn't want to reload data if I was navigating back to a page where I had already loaded data. In the end I had to use flags to determine if I had already loaded data.

Answer (score 0):

you can always define a bool variable/s in the App class( App.xaml.cs ).
they can be accessed from any page by the following method

in App class

`public bool backVariable=false;`

in page1 Page1.xaml.cs
globally or in any method

`App thisApp=Application.Current as App;`

then u can access the boolean variable using

`thisApp.backVariable`